# Qt in Windows: build environment and redistribution problems

Tags: c++, windows, qt, wxwidgets

I want to ask your opinion about one specific aspect of endless "Qt vs wxWidgets" question. Using wxWidgets in Windows, I may continue to work with my prefered build tools and compilers (in my case, Visual Studio). I only need to add wxWidgets include and lib directories to the compiler/linker path. When necessary, I just open some wxWidgets form designer (like DialogBlocks) and make form layout. Executables don't have any additional dependencies and don't cause any problems in redistribution.

On the other hand, Qt comes with its own IDE which tends to be the main development tool (which I don't want). It installs MinGW. It uses qmake, this is one more challenge in integrating Qt to existing build environment. I don't know how to use my existing libraries, developed with VC++, in Qt application. Can I continue to work with Visual Studio or I need to switch completely to Qt Creator? Or use both, building everything but UI in Visual Studio, and UI in Qt Creator? How Qt-based application can be redistributed: should I require MinGW installation on target computer?

How all these problems are solved - I need some directions and opinions from C++ developers working with Qt in Windows.

Edit: It looks like most promising directions are Visual Studio plugin and CMake. I found that Qt plugin supports VS2010, but it requires rebuilding Qt from the source. For VS2008 this plugin works with binary Qt installation - good enough.

Comment: This really is subjective; it belongs on programmers. +1 for a good question though. I suspect you're pretty much stuck with Qt Creator if you really want to use Qt. Related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/88685/why-dont-all-use-qt/88689#88689

Comment: I did not realize the Qt windows build environment was so complex.  I chose wxWidgets over Qt some years ago because of the better licence at the time.  Now I am very glad I did.  I often have to guide clients through setting up a build environment and wxWidgets is enough of a challenge for some of them.

Comment: I addition to all these problems, I found that VC++ CRT memory leaks detector reports a lot of (false?) memory leaks, working with Qt, making impossible to track my own leaks. I am also happy that I chose wxWidgets for my real project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio.  There is a Visual Studio integration plugin that makes it a lot lot easier to develop with Qt in Visual Studio.

As for the wxWidgets vs Qt debate... I use both (on different projects).  I have to say that I would rather use Qt - it has fewer bugs IMO and in general there is an easier workaround if you have problems with the framework (Qt4 is much better in this regard than Qt3 was because the 'pimpl' data is accessible).  However, distribution is slightly more complicated with Qt as you must make sure that you have set included any plugins correctly in your distro (be sure to check that it works on a clean machine that does not have Qt installed).

Comment: I have VS2010, Qt integration is not available. I think I will return to VS2008 to feel better with Qt.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use the whole Qt SDK, you can only install the [libraries for VS](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/windows-cpp-vs2008) (or build from source, if you prefer. The pre-built libraries are for VS2008 but there is a makespec for VS2010 so you can build one yourself, if necessary) and use the [Visual Studio integration](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/visual-studio-add-in).

Answer (score 1):

You can download the Qt "source-only", take a look [here for the latest version](http://get.qt.nokia.com/qt/source/). You can build this library youself using the provided configure tool and MS' nmake...

For example, my typical build looks like this:

```
configure -shared -release -opensource -no-webkit -nomake demos -nomake examples
nmake
```

This will build release-mode Qt dlls, assumes you want to use the LGPL-license (with the -opensource flag), no webkit and upon calling nmake it will not build the demos and examples... Of course, you will have to take a look at all the possible options provided by configure

Comment: Note that "opensource license" is LGPL, which is a relatively restrictive license. Not as restrictive as, say, GPL, but certainly more restrictive than MIT/BSD/BSL/MS-PL/etc.

Comment: @Billy: Thanks, for clarity I have slightly reworded my answer. Although the answer was intended as an example of my typical configure-call, I agree that I should have mentioned LGPL.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use Qt Creator, many people use other IDEs or simple text editors.

qmake is not difficult to use, from a template config you can easily modify a project file by hand. In fact qmake will generate a basic project file for you to get started with.

Use existing libraries as you would in any other project.

You don't need to require a mingw install, you can include essential DLLs in your application directory; but this is the same problem as any other "DLL hell" problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you use cmake as a build system, you can use that to generate project files for visual studio (and eclipse, and ordinary Makefiles, and ..., on any OS). Just install the cmake GUI and select visual studio [myversion] in the appropriate dropdown menu. The only thing to remember then is that you need to make changes to the structure of your project (e.g. adding files) to the cmake CMakeLists.txt files.

Setting up cmake + Qt is pretty easy, and you only have to figure it out once. Googling around a bit should get this setup running in no time.